# Creating a leave absence system using Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, system, excel-2003

I'm totally new to Excel VBA. I am using Microsoft 2003 excel.

What my superior tasked me to do was to create a Leave Management System that tracks down an employee's amount of days left in terms of leave and from there, send an email down to her, her secretary and the employee regarding the status of approved or rejected.

I did try out some codes of VBA.. But I do not know how really the mail sending function works? Do i send the attachment out? Or when i entered some value in the code, it will auto send the whole attachment over? I'm really lost here, thank you!

```
Sub Mail_sheets()
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim last As Long
Dim shname As Long
Dim a As Integer
Dim Arr() As String
Dim N As Integer
Dim strdate As String
For a = 1 To 253 Step 3
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mail").Cells(1, a).Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    last = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mail").Cells(Rows.Count, _
        a).End(xlUp).Row
    N = 0
    For shname = 1 To last
        N = N + 1
        ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To N)
        Arr(N) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mail").Cells(shname, a).Value
    Next shname
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Arr).Copy
    strdate = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy") & " " & _
        Format(Time, "h-mm-ss")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Part of " & ThisWorkbook.Name _
        & " " & strdate & ".xls"
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mail")
        MyArr = .Range(.Cells(1, a + 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, _
            a + 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SendMail MyArr, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mail").Cells(1, a + 2).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
    Kill ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Ron has covered it in his blog. http://www.rondebruin.nl/sendmail.htm, Have a look at it.

Comment: Is there any way you could do this in something other than excel? Programming MS Office is actually very painful, because things frequently don't work quite as documented. If you're stuck with it, I wish you luck, and recommend you spend your free time learning another set of programming technologies.

Comment: @Marcin: With Respect, I disagree with you :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Then very good for you. Do try something else, if you haven't, though, even if only for your own education.

Comment: @Marcin: You missed my point. Users like `newbie` fall under a category who unfortunately have to do what "Boss" says. At one point of time, I was in that very category. And when you are in that category, trust me, the boss always wants it to be done in a particular way and QUICKLY. One unfortunately doesn't have a choice or time to learn new language. If the user was trying to experiment with a particular project then your suggestion definitely makes sense ;)

Comment: All of the relevant data for this application is in the spreadsheet, I presume?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Bosses are, despite the rumours, human. It is possible to ask them if you can use something else. And, if a user has to learn to programme VBA, then they might as well learn to programme in something easier to use.

Comment: @Marcin: Agreed on the `human` part but whats wrong with VBA. Yes there are few limitations but what the user wants can be `easily` done in VBA. If I was making something like that for commercial use then I would have used VB.Net with SQL/MYSQL database to make the project. But then if I was just an employee whose boss wants something done, me suggesting the boss to get me a copy of VB.Net will only complicate things. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout VBA/Office-based development takes many times as long as using a proper programming environment, because of undocumented beahviours, and the lack of support for essential operations.

Comment: @Marcin: It depends on what you are trying to do. I am re-emphasizing my point that what the user wants can be `easily` done in VBA with no complications. And I am speaking from experience as during my early days, I have handled the MIS department as well. We didn't have the luxury to get VB.Net or any other language installed so everything was made in VBA and it worked flawlessly :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm also speaking from experience. In addition, with the magic of the web, you only need to install your computing environment in one place.

Comment: @marcin: I know this discussion can go on if we both want. So straight to the point :) Do you think what the user wants can be easily done in VBA?

Comment: Hello all, I do understand each and every point of view of yours in due respect. What Mr Siddharth has mentioned was correct, she wants it within 1 week. And I do not even know whether she will change her mind or not, it is totally impossible for me to familiarise the VBA language within 1 week! *Grumbles* Once again, thank you Mr Siddharth, I will fiddle around with the codes here and there.

Comment: @Newbie: I recently realized that I have downvoted this question by mistake. I wanted to upvote it. Now it doesn't allow me to. Could you make any small change in the above question so that i can reverse the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example on how to achieve what you want. **Please amend it for your actual needs.**

> > > I did try out some codes of VBA.. But I do not know how really the mail sending function works? Do i send the attachment out?

You don't need to send the entire workbook as an attachment. You can send a simple email stating whether the leave is approved or rejected. If you need to support why you are rejecting or approving the leave then you can paste the relevant cells in the email. See this example.

I am assuming for a moment that you worksheet looks like this.

[image]

Now suppose the employee `Siddharth` wants to take a leave. As we can see in the snapshot, the employee has `0` leaves balance. So the request for leave will be declined and a mail will be shot to the relevant person/Dept

When you run the code, it will ask you to enter the employees name

[image]

and then sends the relevant email.

[image]

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

'~~> To Field in Email
Const strTo As String = "aaa@aaa.com"
'~~> CC field in email. If you do not want to CC then change "bbb@bbb.com" to ""
Const strCC As String = "bbb@bbb.com"

'~~> This is what goes in the body
Const strBody1 As String = "Dear XYZ,"
Const strBody2 As String = "This is in reference to leave request for employee "

Const strBodyApp As String = "The employee has sufficient leave balance and can take the leave"
Const strBodyNotApp As String = "The employee doesn't have sufficient leave balance and hence cannot take the leave"
Const strByeBye  As String = "Thanks and Regards"
Const sender As String = "ABC"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim Ret
    Dim Bal As Long
    Dim Rw As Long

    Ret = Application.InputBox("Please enter the name of the employee who wants to take a leave")

    If Ret = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")

    Set aCell = ws.Columns(2).Find(What:=Ret, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Bal = aCell.Offset(, 5).Value
        Rw = aCell.Row

        If Bal > 0 Then
            Approved Ret, True, Rw
        Else
            Approved Ret, False, Rw
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "The employee " & Ret & " was not found"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Approved(EmpName, app As Boolean, lRow As Long)
    Dim msg As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    If app = True Then
        msg = "<p class=MsoNormal>" & strBody1 & "<o:p></o:p></p>" & vbNewLine & _
               "<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>" & vbNewLine & _
               "<p class=MsoNormal>" & strBody2 & EmpName & ". " & strBodyApp & _
               "<span style='mso-fareast-font-family:""Times New Roman""'><o:p></o:p></span></p>"
    Else
        msg = "<p class=MsoNormal>" & strBody1 & "<o:p></o:p></p>" & vbNewLine & _
               "<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>" & vbNewLine & _
               "<p class=MsoNormal>" & strBody2 & EmpName & ". " & strBodyNotApp & _
               "<span style='mso-fareast-font-family:""Times New Roman""'><o:p></o:p></span></p>"
    End If

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:F1" & ",A" & lRow & ":F" & lRow)

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = strTo
        .CC = strCC
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Leave Status"

        .HTMLBody = msg & _
                    RangetoHTML(rng) & _
                    "<p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:""Times New Roman""'>" & strByeBye & "<o:p></o:p></span></p>" & _
                    "<p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:""Times New Roman""'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>" & _
                    "<p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:""Times New Roman""'>" & sender & "<o:p></o:p></span></p>"

        .Display   '.Send 'To send the email
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

'~~> Taken from http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/folder3/mail4.htm
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2010
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         fileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

**DISCLAIMER**: Since the above code is a basic example, I have not

1) included Error handling (which you should)

2) used basic stuff as `Application.ScreenUpdating`

**SAMPLE FILE**: This link will be active for the next 7 days. I have uploaded a sample file for you to play with :)

http://wikisend.com/download/562482/Sample.xls

HTH

Comment: +1 for not providing a solution, yet guiding the asker on the right path
I agree that this can be easily handled in VBA